# R_kableExtra install

Tags: r, kableextra

I am trying to install `kableExtra` and get the following errors:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘systemfonts’
```

- removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/systemfonts’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘systemfonts’ is not available for package ‘svglite’
- removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/svglite’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘svglite’ is not available for package ‘kableExtra’
- removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/kableExtra’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kableExtra’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: You need to figure out why your install of `systemfonts` failed.  It had a "configuration error".   Find the log, and be specific.

Comment: What operating system are you using?